# Jquery or Javascript:Assigning the Textarea value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea and a input hidden field in a form,

I want the values of textarea to be assigned to hidden field onchange of value in textarea,
though the id attribute of hidden field is dynamic in my system, but I am keeping it static here for the sake of direct reference, below is the code I am trying it out,

```
<textarea rows="3" name="message" class="push_message" onchange="$('#'+<?php echo 
$rowUsers["gcm_regid"];?>).val(this.value);"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="regId" value="" id="APA91bGmks8s9ytYxT43zsIP5bHmIDdTDm6fuqosPOov6EhVk1GShwSN4npSkWcgEcY-BS8glgptqSHIu9UmLHvjAtZjBakF5csjouYOL_S1hN5JdlYkpWpPmjB_nUhbTmVtAho7M6o-W4rsVJorB-ozX9v50YkBMg"/>

here :<?php echo 
    $rowUsers["gcm_regid"];?> == APA91bGmks8s9ytYxT43zsIP5bHmIDdTDm6fuqosPOov6EhVk1GShwSN4npSkWcgEcY-BS8glgptqSHIu9UmLHvjAtZjBakF5csjouYOL_S1hN5JdlYkpWpPmjB_nUhbTmVtAho7M6o-W4rsVJorB-ozX9v50YkBMg
```

Can someone help me up in achieving this task

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error :

```
$('#'+<?php echo $rowUsers["gcm_regid"];?>)
```

Is actually

```
$('#<?php echo $rowUsers["gcm_regid"];?>')
```

Comment: U Saved mee from killing myself

Comment: @OMTheEternity Glad to save a life !

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('textarea[name="message"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="regId"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 $('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() { 
        var textAreaValue=$(this).val();
        $('#hiddenInput').val(textAreaValue);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next to get the element right after it and set its value:

```
onchange="$(this).next().val(this.value);"
```